# Room Transaction rollback or cancel

Tags: android, android-room, android-jetpack

Is Room using rollback as default in `@Transaction`?

Does it only cancel next query inside `@Transaction` without rollbacking?

What it actually does on error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you are refering to implemented methods annotated with `@Transaction` such as:

```
@Transaction
public void transferMoney(String accountA, String accountB, int amount) {
  updateMoney(accountA, -amount);
  updateMoney(accountB, +amount);
}
```

> Is Room using rollback as default in @Transaction?

Yes, if an exception is thrown in the method annotated with `@Transaction` then Room will perform a `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`

> Does it only cancel next query inside @Transaction without rollbacking?

It cancels every subsequent query in the method and rollbacks any changes made by any other query within the method up to the point of failure.

> What it actually does on error?

It rollsback the transaction.

---

If you are referring to `@Query` annotated methods that are also annotated with `@Transaction`, then those are read-only queries, so there is really nothing to rollback, however, when the resulting data is big or the returning data has an `@Relation` then data is guaranteed. See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Transaction