# Updating two Tables at same time but rollback if update fails

Tags: sqlite, sql-update, android-sqlite, android-room, rollback

[image: curerd]

Let's say we have the above diagram. We have two tables, which I want to update.In case one update fails, I want to rollback both updates.

I want the best performance, so I realized there is only one solution which I can think of:

```
viewModel.updateTable1(
    updatedId1 ->{ 
        viewModel.updateTable2(
            updatedId2 ->{ 
                Toast.makeText(this,"great, both succes!!!! :)",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }, 
            er->{
                //somehow a rollback
            }
    }, 
    er->{
        Log.e("error",er.getMessage())
    }
);
```

However I am by FAR not a big fan of my solution as, I need to wait till table1 gets updated and then I can update table2. So my question would be is it possible to update 2 or more tables but ROLLBACK BOTH TRANSACTION in case one update fails?

Comment: A transaction takes care of that. That's the main point, the definition of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option is to run both updates in a single transaction.

An example, albeit in Java, that is purposefully designed to fail (on the 2nd update) and thus rollback the first successful update.

So first we have an Update Method (function in Kotlin) that utilises and update Dao `@Update int update(Bookmark bookmark);` that is in the `AllDao` interface :-

```
public static void updateTwo(TheDatabase db, Bookmark bookmark1, Bookmark bookmark2) {
    boolean updateOk = true;
    AllDao dao = db.getAllDao();
    SupportSQLiteDatabase sdb = db.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase();
    sdb.beginTransaction();
    if (dao.update(bookmark1) > 0) {
        if (dao.update(bookmark2) < 1) {
            Log.d("UPDATETWO","Second Update failed");
            updateOk = false;
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("UPDATETWO","First Update failed to update anything.");
        updateOk = false;
    }
    if (updateOk) {
        Log.d("UPDATETWO","Both updates OK");
        sdb.setTransactionSuccessful(); //<<<<< ONLY SET TRANSACTION OK if both updates (aka ROLLBACK if not both OK)
    }
    sdb.endTransaction();
}
```

- Note SupportSQliteDatabase used but really `runInTransaction` should be used (am looking at using this, so I may update answer)
- Logging included for showing results.
- P.S. I have allowed running on main thread for convenience/brevity

And in an Activity I have code that is designed to not update (i.e. the update fails (albeit that it doesn't it just doesn't update which I assume is what you mean by fail rather than an exception being thrown)):-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TheDatabase db;
    AllDao dao;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this);
        dao = db.getAllDao();
        dao.deleteAll();
        Bookmark b1 = new Bookmark(), b2 = new Bookmark();

        // Insert Row
        b1.setPostTitle("P1");
        b1.setPostUrl("U1");
        b1.setId(dao.insert(b1)); // sets the id so row can be updated

        // Prepare for update
        b1.setPostUrl("URL1"); // change so there is an update to be performed i.e. change U1 to URL1
        // Prepare a second (no-existent so doomed to fail) Row for update
        b2.setPostTitle("P2");
        b2.setPostUrl("U2");
        // Do the update
        Bookmark.updateTwo(db,b1,b2);
        for (Bookmark b: dao.getAll()) {
            Log.d("BOOKMARKINFO","ID = " + b.getId() + " PostTitle = " + b.getPostTitle() + " PostURL =" + b.getPostUrl());
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

The Log :-

```
D/UPDATETWO: Second Update failed
D/BOOKMARKINFO: ID = 1 PostTitle = P1 PostURL =U1
```

i.e. the Row is back to U1 not URL1 (aka ROLLED BACK)

If before the update the line `b2.setId(dao.insert(b2));` is added (so the 2nd row exists and thus will be updated (even though no data is actually change)) then the Log is :-

```
D/UPDATETWO: Both updates OK
D/BOOKMARKINFO: ID = 1 PostTitle = P1 PostURL =URL1
D/BOOKMARKINFO: ID = 2 PostTitle = P2 PostURL =U2
```

i.e. first row is URL1 (aka NOT ROLLED BACK)

- **The above as it stands is only suitable for single row updates as it only checks if any update has been made rather than the number of updates matches.**

**Update**

here's the equivalent using runInTransaction. It appears that "The transaction will be marked as successful unless an exception is thrown in the Runnable." is only if an SQLite Exception is thrown. As such a precarious dao was added to force an exception i.e.

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.ABORT)
long abort(Bookmark bookmark);
```

- Precarious as it assumes that the Bookmark exists and therefore cannot be inserted as the UNIQUE constraint is violated (id column).

The alternative code being :-

```
public static void update2(TheDatabase db,Bookmark b1, Bookmark b2) {
    try {
        db.runInTransaction(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    upd(db, b1, b2);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}

private static void upd(TheDatabase db, Bookmark b1, Bookmark b2) throws Exception {
    boolean updateOk = true;
    AllDao dao = db.getAllDao();
    if (dao.update(b1) > 0) {
        if(dao.update(b2) < 1) {
            updateOk = false;
            Log.d("UPDATETWO","Second Update failed");
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("UPDATETWO","First Update failed to update anything.");
    }
    if (!updateOk) {
        dao.abort(b1); // Force SQLite Exception to ROLLBACK
    } else {
        Log.d("UPDATETWO","Both updates OK");
    }
}
```

The following code in the activity was used for testing :-

```
    dao.deleteAll();
    Bookmark b1 = new Bookmark(), b2 = new Bookmark(), b3 = new Bookmark();

    // Insert Row
    b1.setPostTitle("P1");
    b1.setPostUrl("U1");
    b1.setId(dao.insert(b1)); // sets the id so row can be updated

    // Prepare for update
    b1.setPostUrl("URL1"); // change so there is an update to be performed i.e. change U1 to URL1
    // Prepare a second (no-existent so doomed to fail) Row for update
    b2.setPostTitle("P2");
    b2.setPostUrl("U2");
    // Do the update
    Bookmark.updateTwo(db,b1,b2);
    logInfo("-A1");
    b2.setId(dao.insert(b2));
    Bookmark.updateTwo(db,b1,b2);
    logInfo("-A2");

    b1.setPostUrl("U R L 1");
    b3.setPostTitle("P3");
    b3.setPostUrl("U3");
    Bookmark.update2(db,b1,b3);
    logInfo("-B1");
    b3.setId(dao.insert(b3));
    Bookmark.update2(db,b1,b3);
    logInfo("-B2");
}

private void logInfo(String extra) {
    for (Bookmark b: dao.getAll()) {
        Log.d("BMINFO" + extra,"ID = " + b.getId() + " PostTitle = " + b.getPostTitle() + " PostURL =" + b.getPostUrl());
    }
}
```

This uses both methods **-A** (as per log) using the `SupportSQliteDatabase` the **-B** using `runInStransaction`. The Log :-

```
2021-07-01 13:19:50.944 D/UPDATETWO: Second Update failed
2021-07-01 13:19:50.946 D/BMINFO-A1: ID = 1 PostTitle = P1 PostURL =U1
2021-07-01 13:19:50.949 D/UPDATETWO: Both updates OK
2021-07-01 13:19:50.951 D/BMINFO-A2: ID = 1 PostTitle = P1 PostURL =URL1
2021-07-01 13:19:50.951 D/BMINFO-A2: ID = 2 PostTitle = P2 PostURL =U2
2021-07-01 13:19:50.953 D/UPDATETWO: Second Update failed
2021-07-01 13:19:50.963 D/BMINFO-B1: ID = 1 PostTitle = P1 PostURL =URL1
2021-07-01 13:19:50.963 D/BMINFO-B1: ID = 2 PostTitle = P2 PostURL =U2
2021-07-01 13:19:50.966 D/UPDATETWO: Both updates OK
2021-07-01 13:19:50.969 D/BMINFO-B2: ID = 1 PostTitle = P1 PostURL =U R L 1
2021-07-01 13:19:50.969 D/BMINFO-B2: ID = 2 PostTitle = P2 PostURL =U2
2021-07-01 13:19:50.969 D/BMINFO-B2: ID = 3 PostTitle = P3 PostURL =U3
```

**Edit** re the comment:-

> Wouldnt't the anotation Transaction safe me the "boilercode"

Tried using :-

```
@Transaction
public static boolean update3(AllDao dao,Bookmark b1, Bookmark b2) {
    boolean updateOk = true;
    if (dao.update(b1) > 0) {
        if (dao.update(b2) < 1) {
            updateOk = false;
        }
    }
    if (!updateOk) {
        dao.abort(b1);
    }
    return updateOk;
}
```

However, the abort results in a crash e.g. :-

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: a.a.so67958704javaroomconvertexistingdb, PID: 6136
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{blah....}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: mylist_data.ID (code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
....
```

So I believe that `@Transaction`, unlike `runInTransaction`,  isn't designed for Rollback.

Comment: thats works perfect! I looked up transactions cause thats kinda new to me in room and I came across the Transaction annotation. Wouldnt't the anotation Transaction safe me the "boilercode" using  SupportSQLiteDatabase /db.runInTransaction(new Runnable() {}. Or is the transaction annotation meant for another use?

Comment: @FunnyMoments the problems is that you have to convert what isn't an error into a detectable and appropriately handled rollback. Room and SQLite will consider updating nothing as OK (different matter if the "failed update" is a conflict).

Comment: @FunnyMoments just tried a slightly less bulky update inside `@Trasnaction` but it appears that `@Transaction` doesn't trap exceptions like `runInTransaction` does, so the abort insert causes a crash.

Comment: @FunnyMoments edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57381094/room-transaction-rollback-or-cancel rollback would occure, but I will check it out :) thanks you very much for your help